# Problems with dual boot in an old pc (pentium 4) without UEFI

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, mbr, grub-legacy

I write all of you because I have expended two weks trying to solve this problem, I have seen a lot of youtube videos and read a lot of forums but I cannot fix this.

I want to clarify that I'm only a user but I'm not an expert in linux or windows.I have already installed dual-boot pcs in newer computers but I really really realy need some help! I'm having a lot of troubles trying to have pentium4 pc with dual boot, the idea is to have windows 7 and linux Mint. I also know that it is possible to have a dual OS system in this pc because this pc had windows 7 and it was updated to windows 10, afnter that I installed linux and it was fine, but as W10 was too slow for this pc, I re-installed a version of windows 7 and when I tried to re-install linux, all the problems started.

After installing linux and rebooting, the grub does not work and show the grub-rescue message. I have tried all the standard solutions, changing the root in the grub-rescue terminal, using live usb sessions to install and use grub-installer, boot-repair, grub-customize and in windows, grub2win and easybcd2,4 but I always have this problem. I have triend installing the grub in the harddrive and also in the linux partition. I also have formatted my hard drive and installed windows and linux several times and I always have the same problem. When I want to boot windows I have to use bootrec to rebuild the bcd.

The pc has a pentium 4, cpu 300GHz, RAM 2 Gb, 32bit and a HD of 160 Gb and I have 5 partitions:

- sda1 100MB reserved for the system primary partition
- sda2 C: primary partition NTFS for windows
- sda3 D. primary partition NTFS for storage
- Sda5 Logical partition ext 4, for linux
- sda6 logical partition swap

I don't know if the problem is because I try to install a recent version of linux and the grub assume that I have UEFi and search for efi . It is that, what would be the grub configuration for a pc without UEFI? (I also have tried to install Mint 14 and a few other light distros)
I also have tried with the easybcd2.4 and it allowed me to create a boot menu with windows and linux but it fails to boot linux. I have tried to edit NEoGrub menu.lst file but I cannot find the right configuration. Do you have a sample file that could work for my configuration? I've read that it is based on grub4dos syntax but I have no idea about this.

I want to resume my questions:

- Is it different the grub.cfg file for PCs without UEFI? If it is different, someone could provide an example ( or help me to create) a grub cfg file for a dual windows-linux ?
- I think that it could be easier to change the bcd configuration using the correct menu.lst file, someone could help me to write an appropiate file for my configuration?
- If I'm doing the things in a really wrong direction, could you please show me how I could install the two OS and which version would fit more with my pc?
- Do I need to provide more information related to my boot problem? How could I get it?
- Could this be a problem related with windows and I should need an specific version?

I want to sincerely thanks to the people that will take their time to read this message and for the comments and ideas that you could have.

Answer (score 1):

(This is going to be a "work-in-progress" answer, as more hard facts are needed for a proper answer, but I don't think the necessary background info and instructions will fit into a comment or two.)

This is unlikely to have anything to do with UEFI, as it is quite easy for the installer to detect that UEFI is not available on the system. Most UEFI-capable Linux distributions will detect this and automatically install the BIOS version of GRUB - they are not likely to even offer you a choice!

*Which Linux distribution* are you trying to install?

You've added both `grub2` and `grub-legacy` tags - `grub-legacy` is the obsolete GRUB 0.97 or so, which is not relevant unless you're installing a very old distribution. Even on BIOS/MBR-based systems, GRUB2 is now normally used.

The problem with the classic BIOS/MBR boot process is that the installer will need to predict the BIOS detection order of any disks on the system based on incomplete information. As a workaround, modern GNU GRUB will generate a configuration that includes `search` commands using filesystem GUID/UUID identifiers whenever possible.

Older distributions used to simply write the disk IDs into the configuration file as the installer saw them - and if you installed from USB media, the USB disk may have been misidentified as `(hd0)` by the installer. After unplugging the installation USB stick, the remaining disks will shift their BIOS/GRUB numbering - and the installer may or may not be able to predict this shift correctly.

*What are the actual symptoms?* You said you tried to change the root in GRUB rescue prompt - what exact commands did you use, and what was the response?

When you get to the GRUB rescue mode, type `ls (hd` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see the GRUB identifiers for disks detected by the BIOS. Likewise, you should type `ls (hd0,` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see the partitions on the first HDD in the BIOS list (= whichever disk is selected in BIOS as the boot disk, usually). Does the output make sense given your partitioning?

You might also be hitting the 128 GiB/136.9 GB disk size limit some BIOSes of about the Pentium 4 era had. If the BIOS cannot handle disks with more than 2^28 blocks (= does not have support for LBA48), then it - and also GRUB - will fail to access any partitions beyond that limit. That might explain why Windows works but GRUB fails: with your partitioning scheme, the Linux partitions might be too far into the disk to be accessible by a BIOS suffering from this restriction. The workaround for this is to use a small `/boot` partition located completely below the limit, ideally at the very beginning of the disk.

The `/boot` partition only needs to contain any GRUB modules that are needed and won't fit in the main GRUB image, the GRUB configuration file, and the kernel and initramfs files for the Linux kernel(s) you're trying to boot. Once the Linux kernel gets started and finds its own drivers in initramfs, it will be able to bypass the limits of the BIOS and access the whole disk.

You said:

> I think that it could be easier to change the bcd configuration using the correct menu.lst file

I'm not sure I understand what you're after here - `BCD` is a binary configuration file for the Windows bootloader,  `menu.lst` is for GRUB Legacy and not used at all in changing the BCD.

Comment: Grub is installed in the linux partition, when booting it says error: no such partition. When I typed ls it showed the following: (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hdo, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1) (fd0) I guess that it makes references to the 3 primary partitions. When I try ls (to any of these partitions) it says Filesystem is unknown. I moved the logical partition containing linux and swap right after the partition with windows and ls gives: (hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hdo, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1) (fd0) It does not show the linux partitions, could it be because it's a logical partition?

Comment: to confirm if the grub menu only shows primary partitions. I create the following partition table :

- sda1 100MB reserved for the system primary partition
- sda2 C: primary partition NTFS for windows
- sda3 primary partition ext4, for linux
- sda4 extended
- sda5 logical partition linux swap 
- sda6 logical partition NTFS for storage. 
ls gives: 

(hd0) 
(hd0,msdos3) 
(hdo, msdos2) 
(hd0, msdos1) 
(fd0) 

it seem that it detects now the linux partition, but when doing ls (hd0,msdos3) it says: 'error: no such partition'

Comment: I also typed set and it shows: 
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5

then I tried: 
set boot=(hdo,msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal

--> no such partition

according to my partitions table, msdos5 should be the logical partition containing the swap, therefore I also tried to do the commands with msdos3 (because the linux partition is there), with msdos1 and msdos2 and I get the same answer.

Comment: What are the sizes for the partitions you're using? GRUB does not probe the partitions on its own, it simply uses BIOS's knowledge. If your system BIOS has the 128 GiB limitation I mentioned, it might explain this sort of odd behavior.

Comment: The size of each OS partition is aprox. 20 Gb. swap = 4Gb and another NTFS partition  for storage is aprox. 115 Gb.

Comment: Regarding my question about the menu.lst in bcd, I was not sure how to express it but after some reading, I think that the correct question was to edit the bcd configuration, I mean, edit the windows bootloader